# «...сквер Алёнка в Керчи». Кавычить ли название сквера?

Tags: кавычки

«...сквер Алёнка в Керчи». Кавычить ли название сквера?

Answer (score 1):

Если верить [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2), то кавычки всё же нужны.

> 2. Условные (символические) названия, заключаемые в кавычки.
>
> Реальные собственные имена и условные наименования различаются синтаксической сочетаемостью. Ср.: *Большой театр, Театр сатиры, Театр на Юго-Западе* – это реальные собственные имена, в них присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость, кавычки не нужны. Но: *театр «Современник», театр «Школа современной пьесы»* – условные наименования, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым словом. Они заключаются в кавычки. Аналогично: ***парк Дружбы**, но: **парк «Сокольники»**, Коммунистическая партия Российской Федерации,* но: *партия «Яблоко»* и т. д.

Я думаю, слово *"сквер"* ближе всего к слову *"парк"* (и к слову *"сад"* из Галининого ответа тоже), поэтому к нему должно это точно так же относиться.

Сравните с основными географическими родовыми наименованиями, такими как например *гора, вулкан, долина ледник, остров.* Синтаксически несочетаемые с ними названия пишутся без кавычек, например *гора Мтацминада, вулкан Везувий, озеро Байкал, долина Тамашлык.*

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, заключаются ли в кавычки названия садов,
>   парков, национальных парков и заповедников, когда наименование
>   условное, не сочетающееся синтаксически с родовым словом (сад «Эдем»,
>   парк «Звезда», заповедник «Три столба», национальный парк
>   «Чинкве-Терре» и т. п.). И как это доказать?
>
> «Грамота.ру» и словарь В. В. Лопатина «Прописная или строчная?»
>   приводят такие примеры в кавычках.

**[источник](https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/1429283.html)**